# Excel Date Filter not grouping dates

Tags: excel, date

I am pulling data from another spreadsheet and have a filter on the column header. The dates range from 2015 to 2018 off all months, weeks and days. Some of the dates are not grouping e.g. 15/03/2018 is loose underneath the 2018, 2017, 2016 and 2015 collapsible boxes.

All dates has come from the same source spreadsheet and the Marco formats them all as did/mm/yyyy when copying over.

Comment: `did` or `dd`, as far as the days are concerned? :-)

Comment: My bad, typo  “dd”

Answer (score 3):

I have found the formula *DATE(YEAR(a1),MONTH(a1),DAY(a1))* will translate both strings that look like dates and actual dates into a date format.

Filtering and sorting behavior should then be consistent down the column.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar problem by copying the column to notepad, and reinserting it. After this all dates were in the same format.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the dates, and go to data -> Text to columns -> OK

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Excel recognizes the whole column as a set of dates.

Grouping requires **all** cells to be formatted as dates. Grouping will only work if there are no empty or text cells in a range and all cells have the same date format.

You may try the following steps to correct number format in the range:

- remove any number formats (Home -> Clear -> Clear Formats...). After this step your date values shall look like numbers (e.g. 43284, 43285 etc.)
- (optional) multiply the whole range by 1 (Copying "1" from a single cell and using "Paste Special"). This step effectively converts all cell formats to numeric
- (optional) use filter to check if there are any empty / text cells left and fill them with numeric values (e.g. zeroes)
- finally, apply the date format (Home -> Number -> Long Date)

Comment: Problem encounter at step one! When I convert the entire row to General, the dates change to numbers e.g. 43378, however, some stay as 20/05/2018 regardless of what I format the cell as

Comment: This step effectively identifies whether any dates have incorrect format (as in your case). These dates should be corrected manually (you may use filtering / find and replace for doing that).

Try entering them again in a correct format. (Edit cell, then press "enter").

Comment: additionally, you may want to check whether ANY of the cell returns an error. Mine was returning N/A and removing it from the source table fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. Where the date is staying at dd/mm/yyyy, replace "/01/" with " JAN " etc.  The cell should then convert back to number e.g. 43378 when you change to Text, if they do, you can then format cell to the date layout you wish, and viola.....